# How to Inject Custom CSS or JavaScript into a Third-Party iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Looking for ways to customize the appearance or functionality of content within a third-party iframe on a webpage? Share your insights on appending or injecting your own CSS or JavaScript code into iframes while addressing challenges posed by the same-origin policy. What techniques or best practices do you recommend?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("iframe").on("load", function(e) {
            var iframeContent = $(this).contents();
            iframeContent.find('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only legal way to do this is to reach out to the provider of the third party site you wish to modify and pay them to produce a custom version of the site for you.